# Trouble getting gradle project building in Intellij: Task 'compileJava' is ambiguous

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I am attempting to get

```
https://github.com/KodeinKoders/Playground-Demo-Crypto (commit 2a9b2b9)
```

Repository to build.

After doing some updates of tooling MacOS & XCode. And addition of the following override to gradle build file:

```
tasks.getByName<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.native.tasks.KotlinNativeSimulatorTest>("iosX64Test") {
    deviceId = "iPhone 14"
}
```

I am able to build within command line use

```
gradle build
```

On

- MacOS: 13.2
- XCode: 14.2

However, when I run build within IntelliJ. I get the following error:

```
Task 'compileJava' is ambiguous in root project 'DemoCrypto'. Candidates are: 'compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac', 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac', 'compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac', 'compileReleaseJavaWithJavac', 'compileReleaseUnitTestJavaWithJavac'.
```

The IntelliJ notifications show:

```
Executing tasks: [:compileDebugSources, :compileDebugUnitTestSources, :compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :compileJava, :testClasses] in project /usr/local/workplace/sandbox-kotlin-thorg/Playground-Demo-Crypto
```

Prior to build failure.

I am new to gradle. I don't know where this list of tasks that intellij chooses to use for build is coming from? I am also confused by fact that running:

```
grep -r "compileDebugSources" .
```

From within the project root leads to 0 matches.

So the questions are:

- How does IntelliJ choose to use that particular list of tasks to for its build. Given that `compileDebugSources` doesnt even exist in the project.
- Advice on getting the build to work in IntelliJ?

Comment: I would recommend using Android Studio. It'll know what to do. I'm an android dev and I wouldn't know how to set up IntelliJ correctly for an Android project. I know it is possible though and some do that, but you need to have a good reason to make it worth while.